# find SQL Server Tools installation path in 64-bit and 32-bit systems

Tags: inno-setup

I am having problems installing SQL Server 2005 Express Edtion on 64-bit machines.
The problem seems to be that the system does not find sqlcmd (called from ShellExec).
I believe it has to do with the system not finding the right Path environmental variable.
So, I need to find the full path to sqlcmd.exe.
I found out how to do this in 32-bit systems (check the registry for 
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ClientSetup)

However, I do not know what to look for in 64-bit machines, and I read a post warning it might be installed under WoW, but in other locations too.

Does anyone know how to make sure I get the right path?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that if you use the `ArchitectureInstallIn64Bit` Setup directive in your innosetup script this will let you get into the 64bit registry. At that point you should be able to query both bits of registry i.e.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ClientSetup
```

and

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Tools\ClientSetup
```

Sorry I haven't tested this but this helped us with a similar situation a while ago.

Edit: Actually a colleague pointed out that innosetup also has psuedo keys like HKLM64 which can be used as well.